# Magento turn off URL rewrites for invisible products

Tags: magento-1.8, url-rewrite

I have my products made as "configurable products" and it's around 300 of them. And they have around 10-20 simple products associated (each). But 2 of my configurable products have around 3000 simples.
So it is around 10.000 simple products that are set to 'not visible individually'. And of course magento creates for them url rewrites, and reindexing it takes too long.
**Is it possible to turn off url rewrites for 'not visible' products?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use the module [Dn'D Patch Index URL](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dn-d-patch-index-url-1.html) for that and have very positive experiences with it.

There's also the more up-to-date [Loewenstark_UrlIndexer](https://github.com/mklooss/Loewenstark_UrlIndexer) module that is supposed to do the same, but I haven't had time to test it yet.

Comment: We are using DnD and it works like a charm in EE 1.12

Comment: I am using Dn'D Patch Index URL and I am generally satisfied. I faced one problem with url keys that end with a number - it generates urls like `product-name-with-number-12345 => product-name-with-number-12345-1.html`. Since it is quite popular thread, maybe someone could describe his experience with second module Loewenstark_UrlIndexer? I haven't used it so far.

Comment: Loewenstark_UrlIndexer does not seem to work with 1.9. It speeds up the indexing hugely, but it is not creating all relevant rewrites e.g. if a url_key is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711099/how-to-disable-simple-product-url-rewrite-management-by-magento

and than take a look at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php`.

You are interested `getVisibleInSiteVisibilities()` method. This method returns an array of integers, containing info about the status of a product.

Take a look in  `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Visibility.php`. At line 136 (Magento 1.7.0.2) is defined a method named `getOptionsArray()`, which will give an idea about the different statuses.

Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately `getVisibleInSiteVisibilities()` and `getVisibility()` don't return anything.