# How to turn off URL rewrites for products not visible individually in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, optimization

I have configurable products which in `visible` on the website. All it's associated simple/virtual products are `not visible individually` on the site.

How I can turn off url_rewrites of these simple/virtual products which is `not visible individually` ?

Comment: chk this url https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17607/magento-turn-off-url-rewrites-for-invisible-products

Comment: That is for Magento 1. I need something similar for Magento 2.